# Splitting lines read from file into dictionary key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I have a file in the following format:

```
key1/value1
key2/value2
key3/value3
...
```

I want to read it into a dictionary. I have written a following code which accomplishes this:

```
 with open(filename, 'r') as dir_file:
    return {line.split('/')[0]: line.split('/')[1] for line in dir_file.readlines()}
```

However, it seems to me that invoking `split()` method twice is a bad code, and there must be a simpler/better way to split the line into a key-value pair that I'm missing here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
>>> with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
...     d = dict(line.strip().split('/') for line in f)
...
>>>
>>> d
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to remove `\n` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
new_dict = {a:b for a, b in [i.strip('\n').split("/") for i in open('filename.txt')]}
```